# Why does Konakawa keep seeing himself in his dreams, why is he haunted by himself?

Tags: paprika

It really messed me up when Konakawa keeps seeing himself in dreams again and again and is haunted by his friends.

I'm hoping that someone could explain me that segment about his dreams and his friend who gets killed.

What does it exactly mean? Is it his past and present getting interlinked or is it just a dream?